# Capybara not setting off jquery on blur to set autosave

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to run capybara tests to test my jquery autosave on a view.  The problem is when I switch input fields jQuery onBlur is not being activated.  When I manually test through the browser it works fine.

Has anyone had any trouble activating on blur with capybara?

Here are 3 lines of code that switch input fields:

```
find(:css, "#school_data_selection_code_1").select "B"
find(:css, "#per_allocation_1").set "33"
find(:css, "#involvement_reservations_1").set "44"
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are changing fields please

Comment: Updated with an example of changing fields with capybara.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try

```
page.find('#element').trigger('blur')
page.find('#element').set 'value'
```

Let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of capybara-webkit (currently 1.5.1) doesn't fire blur or focus events for select tags, but there's a fix on master for this which will hopefully be released soon. You can try the master branch, which has some improvements for input events.